# Write $f(x) = (3x^3+|x|)/x$ as a piecewise function (rational function)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Write $f(x) = (3x^3+|x|)/x$ as a piecewise function

I'm really confused with this one can you guys please help me out

Comment: Well, do you know what $|x|$ is?

Comment: I haven't done calculus for 3 years and I need help for this would you be able to help me find out what the piecewise function is? thanks

Comment: This isn't a calculus question, though: The question is checking your understanding of *what* $|x|$ means. Do you know the definition of $|x|$ as a function?

Comment: Yeah definition of |x| would be the distance of x from zero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$f(x)=\frac{3x^3+x}{x}=3x^2+1$$ for $x>0$ and 
$$f(x)=\frac{3x^3-x}{x}=3x^2-1$$ for $x<0$

Comment: so would the final answer be f(x) = 3x^2-1 x>0 and 3x^2-1 x<0

Comment: Yes, of course. For $x>0$ we have $f(x)=3x^2+1$.

Comment: Thank you for your help Michael greatly appreciated!

Comment: You are welcome!